# Giving Tzedakah Less than a Perutah

Tags: money, tzedakah-charity, shiurim-measurements

The consensus among poskim is that a prutah is 1/40 of a gram of silver, which is usually more than 1 cent but less than 5 cents. So if a person only gives a penny to tzedakah (let's say that is all that he has, or he wants to do the [mitzvah many times](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7966/jewish/Epistle-21.htm)) is it considered that he did a mitzvah or does giving tzedakah need to be with the lowest halachic amount of money, a perutah?

[See תוס' קידושין ג ע"ב ד"ה ואשה: "less than a worth of a perutah is not considered money" and many more where less than a peruta is not considered giving at all (regarding kiddushin)]

Comment: Don't you think this question is kinda missing the point of tzedakka?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think so, see the Gemara  Bava Basra 9b: כל פרוטה ופרוטה מצתרפת לחשבון גדול - All the individual coins [given to charity] add up to a great amount”. (Seemingly less than a prutah also has the same line reasoning.) Also, see Tanya epistle 21 and 30 which explains this concept.

Comment: There was no coin less than a pruta in talmudic times, so one would be asking aboutn giving a date worth less than ashave prutalike kiddushin 46a. Giving food is Tzedaka

Answer (score -1):

[Chachmas Adam 144](https://www.sefaria.org/Chokhmat_Adam.144?lang=bi) writes that one is supposed to give according to his means and as per the needs of the poor. Thus I conclude that if somehow 1 penny would be sufficient for the intended poor person needs and overall you are giving proportionately to what you can afford to give, then you are fulfilling the mitzvah. There is no minimum amount or shiur of a prutah for tzedakah.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question. I am referring to the fact that in many cases less than prutah is not even considered money. I don't see how this addresses that issue.

Comment: My apologies if it wasn't a satisfying reply but this is what you wrote "So if a person only gives a penny to tzedakah ... is it considered that he did a mitzvah". I merely pointed out that there is no minimum of a prutah here and that, yes, if it satisfies the criteria cites in the C.A, then why not? Remember, you do not need to give money, you can give rocks if that is what he needs. Your helping him where he needs help.

Comment: You didn't point it out. You asserted it. There's not much reason provided to think you are right.